# HTML Input field within a mathjax tex equation

Tags: html, mathjax, tex, input-field

I've got a question on Mathjax.

I'm attempting to include html input fields such as:

```
<input id="up" type="text">
```

within a tex equations.

For now, I tried a lot like:

```
$$ \frac{<input id="up" type="text"/>}{1} $$
```

This won't work at all.
Is there a possibility to do so?

Comment: I tried to do it the other way around "mathjax within input field"... For your problem: The MathML way: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21171107/1066234

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible. MathJax formats mathematical expressions presented using specific syntax. There is no provision for HTML tags in the syntaxes.